# ios8 iPad uiwebview crashes while displaying popover when user taps HTML5 input field with type date

Tags: ios, html, ipad, uiwebview

I am trying to click input date field through ipad webview , On multiple clicks app is crashing with the following errors

**"Application tried to represent an active popover presentation: "**

is there any work around for fixing this issue either from ios native code or from web side ?

The same url I tried in safari, it's not causing any problem.

Comment: I've seen the same thing happen intermittently with <select> elements.  (Tapping on one select box while another is open.)

Comment: The underlying problem is probably the same as:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908729/ios8-ipad-uiwebview-crashes-while-displaying-popover-when-user-taps-drop-down-li