# UIWebViewTerminating app due to UIPopoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

In `iOS 8` `UIWebView` I loaded a html page which has selection options via `popover`. `Webview` opens the native `popover` to show the options but the app is crashing when tapping the buttons.
In `iOS 7` its working fine. Following is the error message in `iOS 8`.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController
>   () should have a non-nil
>   sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'

Comment: This link helped in fixing the issue. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908729/ios8-ipad-uiwebview-crashes-while-displaying-popover-when-user-taps-drop-down-li)

Answer (score 0):

After iOS8 you need to specify sourceView.

```
#define IS_IOS_8_AND_GREATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8)

if (IS_IOS_8_AND_GREATER) {
        activityController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
        activityController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = self.shareButton.frame;
}
```

and after that present it

```
[self presentViewController:activityController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay. In my case I don't have the button in my control to specify the SourceRect as the button is in the web view. The link specified in above post fixed my issue.