# UIWebView Crashing on Drop Down

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

We are loading HTML with Select control (Drop Down) in UIWebView and when we click on Drop down, the app is crashing. This is happening only when  text having lengthy text, but works fine with short Text.

When we debugged, we found its an issue with UILabel in UIPopoverController coming from UIWebView. When UILabel has text with 2 lines, this issue is happening, single line its fine. We are unable to identify the issue whether its with Storyboard or Settings...etc.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is the Crash

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1bd3, 0x034ad930 CoreFoundation`CFArrayGetValueAtIndex + 112, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
frame #0: 0x034ad930 CoreFoundation`CFArrayGetValueAtIndex + 112
frame #1: 0x007d1b41 CoreText`TCharStream::CopyBreakIterator(__CFString const*) + 261
frame #2: 0x007d18f4 CoreText`TCharStream::FindLineBreak(CFRange, bool, __CFString const*) const + 246
frame #3: 0x00758a4a CoreText`TTypesetter::SuggestLineBreak(TLine const&, long, double, double) + 328
frame #4: 0x007586b9 CoreText`CTLineSuggestLineBreakWithOffset + 55
frame #5: 0x0839d89f UIFoundation`__NSStringDrawingEngine + 20275
frame #6: 0x08398940 UIFoundation`-[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:] + 201
frame #7: 0x01b265c1 UIKit`-[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 1425
frame #8: 0x01b25e7e UIKit`-[UILabel textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:] + 85
frame #9: 0x01d1d0cb UIKit`-[UITableViewCellLayoutManager intrinsicContentSizeForCell:] + 554
frame #10: 0x01c16594 UIKit`-[UITableViewCell sizeThatFits:] + 46
frame #11: 0x02092ade UIKit`-[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:] + 130
frame #12: 0x01c01c9f UIKit`-[UITableViewCell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:] + 220
frame #13: 0x01a3f847 UIKit`-[UITableView _heightForCell:atIndexPath:] + 386
frame #14: 0x01a302fb UIKit`__53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 2244
frame #15: 0x019987af UIKit`+[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 82
frame #16: 0x019987f8 UIKit`+[UIView(Animation) _performWithoutAnimation:] + 40
frame #17: 0x01a2fa2f UIKit`-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 355
frame #18: 0x01a381da UIKit`-[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 503
frame #19: 0x01a3829e UIKit`-[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 77
frame #20: 0x01a11a6b UIKit`-[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3034
frame #21: 0x01a2c3d1 UIKit`-[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 222
frame #22: 0x019a1dd1 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 608
frame #23: 0x02f55771 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
frame #24: 0x0061f28f QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 152
frame #25: 0x00613115 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 397
frame #26: 0x00612f70 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 26
frame #27: 0x005713c6 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 284
frame #28: 0x0057278c QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 392
frame #29: 0x00572e58 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
frame #30: 0x034fa9de CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
frame #31: 0x034fa920 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
frame #32: 0x034f035a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1226
frame #33: 0x034efbcb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
frame #34: 0x034ef9fb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #35: 0x04d4224f GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
frame #36: 0x04d4208c GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #37: 0x019168b6 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1526
```

* frame #38: 0x000f85bd `main(argc=1, argv=0xbff5e584) + 141 at main.m:16
    frame #39: 0x04400ac9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: It doesn't give any exception. Crashes at main() function only. And I can only get stack trace by typing bt in console during crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved. The issue was because of hardcoding "AppleLanguages" NSDefaults Key to a String. When UIWebview tries to show UILabel it tries to fetch AppleLanguages as Array and crashing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26692948/4206060

In short, put this into your web view delegate:

```
-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_USEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(),
               ^{
                   [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion];
               });
}
```

Comment: I have already checked that Article, but this issue is different which is getting from UIWebView. I tried this call back, but no luck.