# Cordova Select Option Crash iOS [iPad]

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Cordova is not properly responding to user touch when selecting the following anywhere within my app

```
<select class="FlatSelect select large-input col">
   <option value="Customer Satisfaction">Customer Satisfaction</option>
   <option value="Manager Discount">Manager Discount</option>
   <option value="Competitor Coupon">Competitor Coupon</option>
   <option value="Bad Card">Bad Card</option>
   <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

In fact the app either crashes or does not respond. Below is the crash error.

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView   _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182392db0 0x1819f7f80 0x182392cf8 0x1877267b4 0x18772612c 0x187a3cdd4 0x187501374 0x1875010e8 0x18784833c 0x18779b0c8 0x1877a8a80 0x1874da5a4 0x182348728 0x1823464cc 0x1823468fc 0x182270c50 0x183b58088 0x187552088 0x100040878 0x181e0e8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Version Info Below

`Cordova 5.3.1`
`cordova-ios 3.9.2`
`ionic 1.7.14`

An idea how solve this issue?

Comment: read this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7694. It has some links to possible solutions

Comment: @jcesarmobile thanks for your response. Seems like theirs nothing we can do.

Comment: Did you read this link on the comments? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908729/ios8-ipad-uiwebview-crashes-while-displaying-popover-when-user-taps-drop-down-li

Comment: @jcesarmobile yea I used the highest rated answer, no dice.

Comment: @andrewoodleyjr - Were you able to resolve this issue? How did you do it?

Comment: @nOObiOS Nah, I don't believe I was.

Comment: Then wat did you do with the issue? Because I m facing the exact same issue...