# WKWebView freezing the app iOS 14, Failed to present a context menu for configuration with identifier _UIDatePickerCompactEditor

Tags: wkwebview, uidatepicker, ios14, xcode12, wkwebviewconfiguration

Presenting WKWebView to show web form, webview load successfully with following error **"Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=5 "JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type}**", after loading webview clicked on date field and app freezes with following error **"Failed to present a context menu for configuration with identifier _UIDatePickerCompactEditor. This is likely due to a different presentation occurring during the lifecycle of the interaction."**

The web url working fine on iOS 13 and older and as well in xcode simulator safari.

HTML Tag:

```
<input type="date" name="ScheduleViewing/Date" id="ScheduleViewing/Date" class="form-control placeholder" value="" placeholder="Meeting Date *" style="background-color: transparent; position: relative; z-index: 1; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
```

iOS Code:

```
WKWebView *wkwebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    wkwebView.navigationDelegate = self;
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@" some url"];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [wkwebView loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self.view addSubview:wkwebView];
```

Answer (score 0):

I met same error message and finally I fixed it.

But in my case, HTML is not `<input type="date">` but `<select>`. It is different point with your case.

### My solution

My view controller's `present(_:animated:completion:)` method was overridden like below:

```
    override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        }
    }
```

This code was written few years ago so that fix some problem occurs on iPad. The problem and solution is described in this question.

[ios8 iPad uiwebview crashes while displaying popover when user taps drop down list HTML select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908729/ios8-ipad-uiwebview-crashes-while-displaying-popover-when-user-taps-drop-down-li)

This code worked fine with old iOS (like iOS8,9), but I think this code may bring some side effects with recent iOS.

After I remove this overridden method, my app no longer produces such error.

Please check your `present(_:animated:completion:)` method is overridden or not.